# CSS align div vertically with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="content-one yellow" style="min-height: 365px;">
    <div class="content-one-inner">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img src="" alt="Accenture tshirt">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1 class="desktop">
                <span class="lev-1">
                    <span>CREATE</span> 
                    <span>YOUR</span>
                </span>
                <span class="lev-2">
                    <span>UNIQUE</span> 
                    <span>TEE</span>
                </span>
            </h1>
            <div class="text-wrapper">
                <p> </p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <a class="next" href=""><span>Build your design</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`content-one` has a `min-height` calculated by JS which gets the height of the screen like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateWindowHeight () {
        var currentHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.content-one').css('min-height', currentHeight - 132);
    }

    updateWindowHeight();

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        updateWindowHeight();
    });
});
```

I then have a CSS rule like so:

```
.content-one .content-one-inner {
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
}
```

This centers the div correctly however if the content of it increases or the screen is smaller in height then the `.content-one-inner` gets hidden under the header rand footer.

How can I write my css that if the screen is smaller or the content increases the div (content-one) is still centered but hidden under header and footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `flexbox` evangelist I would suggest `flexbox` :)

Then we will need to add code directly to the `parent` so `div.content-one`, which would look like this

```
.content-one {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Here comes [codePen](http://codepen.io/kejt/pen/pRwxWN)
with solution